# How can i show multiple row data in same row with separate column

Tags: oracle

I have a table name ID_TXN,where "RECONCILE_SL" column has multiple txn where 1txn have multiple contra txn.I want to show them like following......

```
                            My Table Data

| RECONCILE_SL | AMOUNT_DR | AMOUNT_CR | TR_REF_NO   | TRN_DATE  |
| ------------ | --------- | --------- | ----------- | ----------|
| 280874       | 0         | 200000    | 1703700164  | 07-Feb-17 |
| 280874       | 0         | 200000    | 1703900110  | 09-Feb-17 |
| 280874       | 0         | 200000    | 1704400070  | 14-Feb-17 |
| 280874       | 200000    | 0         | AIBIF170137 | 07-Feb-17 |
| 280874       | 400000    | 0         | AIBIF170149 | 09-Feb-17 |

                            My Desire Result

| TRN_DATE  | TR_REF_NO   | AMOUNT_DR | AMOUNT_CR | ContraTRN_DATE | ContraTR_REF_NO | Contra AMOUNT_DR | Contra AMOUNT_CR | RECONCILE_SL |
|-----------|-------------|-----------|-----------|----------------|-----------------|------------------|------------------|--------------|
| 07-Feb-17 | AIBIF170137 | 200000    |           | 07-Feb-17      | 1703700164      |                  | 200000           | 280874       |
| 09-Feb-17 | AIBIF170149 | 400000    |           | 09-Feb-17      | 1703900110      |                  | 200000           | 280874       |
|           |             |           |           | 14-Feb-17      | 1704400070      |                  | 200000           | 280874       |
```

Comment: On StackOverflow we care about high quality questions and answers. 
Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask a question again. This will ensure that your questions live up to Stackoverflow's standards.
You should also update this question after reading the guide.

Comment: What is contra txn?

Comment: Thanks @AnkitBajpai for editing my Question.
Actually contra transaction(txn) means "one/multiple transaction done against one/multiple transaction"
In here against TR_REF_NO (AIBIF170137 & AIBIF170149 )two Debit transaction done for total 60k and against these two transaction 
there done other three Credit transaction TR_REF_NO (1703700164,1703900110,1704400070) for total 60k

Now i need to show this in one group(group by) against "RECONCILE_SL" in mentioned format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add artificial sequence (`rn`) using function `row_number()` and self join your data, something like:

```
select reconcile_sl, 
       dr.trn_date date_dr, dr.amount_dr, dr.tr_ref_no ref_no_dr,
       cr.trn_date date_cr, cr.amount_cr, cr.tr_ref_no ref_no_cr
  from (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by reconcile_sl order by tr_ref_no) rn 
        from id_txn t where amount_dr > 0) dr
  full join (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by reconcile_sl order by tr_ref_no) rn 
        from id_txn t where amount_cr > 0) cr
  using (reconcile_sl, rn)
```

Test:

```
create table id_txn (RECONCILE_SL number(8), AMOUNT_DR number(8), AMOUNT_CR number(8), 
                     TR_REF_NO varchar2(15), TRN_DATE date);

insert into id_txn values(280874,      0, 200000, '1703700164',  date '2017-02-07');
insert into id_txn values(280874,      0, 200000, '1703900110',  date '2017-02-09');
insert into id_txn values(280874,      0, 200000, '1704400070',  date '2017-02-14');
insert into id_txn values(280874, 200000,      0, 'AIBIF170137', date '2017-02-07');
insert into id_txn values(280874, 400000,      0, 'AIBIF170149', date '2017-02-09');
```

Result:

```
RECONCILE_SL DATE_DR     AMOUNT_DR REF_NO_DR       DATE_CR     AMOUNT_CR REF_NO_CR
------------ ----------- --------- --------------- ----------- --------- ---------------
      280874 2017-02-07     200000 AIBIF170137     2017-02-07     200000 1703700164
      280874 2017-02-09     400000 AIBIF170149     2017-02-09     200000 1703900110
      280874                                       2017-02-14     200000 1704400070
```

Comment: So many thanks @Ponder Stibbons.
I solved my problem depending on your query.
Finally I thanks you again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's I write my solution(Query)

```
SELECT  *
 FROM (SELECT acc_no
             ,dr.trn_date ledger_trn_date
             ,dr.tr_ref_no tr_ref_no
             ,dr.amount_dr
             ,dr.amount_cr
             ,cr.trn_date contra_trn_date
             ,cr.tr_ref_no contra_tr_ref_no
             ,cr.amount_dr contra_amount_dr
             ,cr.amount_cr contra_amount_cr
             ,rec_category
             ,reconcile_sl
             ,process_user
             ,type_of_recons
        FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY reconcile_sl ORDER BY tr_ref_no) rn
                FROM ID_TXN t
               WHERE acc_type = 'S') dr
              FULL JOIN (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY reconcile_sl ORDER BY tr_ref_no) rn
                           FROM ID_TXN t
                          WHERE acc_type = 'N') cr
                      USING (reconcile_sl
                            ,acc_no
                            ,rec_category
                            ,process_user
                            ,type_of_recons
                            ,rn)) m
WHERE    acc_no = '101974'
        AND reconcile_sl = 280874
        AND EXISTS
                 (SELECT 1
                    FROM ID_TXN h
                   WHERE trn_date BETWEEN :day_1 AND :day_2
                     AND m.reconcile_sl = h.reconcile_sl)
ORDER BY reconcile_sl, ledger_trn_date, contra_trn_date

Result:

reconcile_sl ledger_trn_date  ledger_tr_ref_no  amount_dr   amount_cr  contra_trn_date contra_tr_ref_no contra_amount_dr  contra_amount_dr  rec_category  process_user  type_of_recons
------------ ---------------  ----------------  ---------  ----------  --------------- ---------------- ----------------  ----------------  ------------  ------------  --------------
      280874       07/feb/17       aibif170137     200000           0        07/feb/17       1703700164                0            200000              s-n         saleh                 m
      280874       09/feb/17       aibif170149     400000           0        09/feb/17         1703900110                0            200000              s-n         saleh                 m
      280874                                                                 14/feb/17         1704400070                0            200000              s-n         saleh                 m
```